# Get unique NSArray of objects based on key

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, key-value-coding

I have an `NSArray` of custom objects and would like to filter down that array to be unique on a specific key. Most of the things I've seen while searching for an answer involve using `valueForKey:`, `valueForKeyPath:` or `@distinctUnionOfObjects` but those return arrays of values for that key. I want the whole object instead.

The objects are subclassed `PFObject`s from Parse so they are KVC compliant, and I would like them to be filtered on the `objectId` key.

Comment: It would help if you provided more details in your question about what the objects are in your array and what value the filtering should be done on.

Comment: I added some more info but its a pretty generic question and could be applied to any key for any KVO object.

Comment: It's not generic at all. Your needs are very specific. What should the result be if two different objects with lots of different values happen to have the same "key"? Which object do you want?

Comment: [Create an NSSet from NSArray based on property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15262198)

Comment: You're probably right, filtering on the 'objectId' key means there would be duplicates of the exact same Parse object but they would be different to the system with different addresses. So I guess it should just pick one they way it would if it were choosing unique strings from an array.

Comment: I was really just wondering if there was an sdk method for this problem instead of getting the unique 'objectId' strings and looping through the objects and putting the ones I wanted in an array.

Comment: There is unfortunately nothing built-in that does exactly this.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in a category on NSArray:

```
-(NSArray*)arrayFilteredForUniqueValuesOfKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath
{
    NSMutableSet*   valueSeen = [NSMutableSet new];

    return [self filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        id value = [evaluatedObject valueForKeyPath:keyPath];

        if(![valueSeen containsObject:value])
        {
            [valueSeen addObject:value];
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }]];
}
```

Of course, the concept is kind of flawed since you really have no way of determining which of the n objects that have any give value for the keyPath you really wanted (in this case you get the first one)